# tesseract giving a different result in a file than a stdout when recognizing chinese picture

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

## Environment

Operation System: win7

Tesseract Version: 5.0

## Problem

I download `chi_sim.traineddata` file from https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/4.00/chi_sim.traineddata. I put the `chi_sim.traineddata` file in the `tessdata` directory.

After I finished it. I want to try to recognize the mandarin character's picture.

[image]

### works with a file as the output

I tried to recognize this picture in a command line with a file as the output.

```
E:\data>tesseract target.png out_file -l chi_sim --psm 7
```

I open the `out_file.txt` file. The file's content is bellow:

```
你 好 , 中 国
```

It works well with output as a file.

### doesn't work with stdout as the output

I run the command line with the `stdout` as output. and tried to recognize the same picture.

```
E:\data>tesseract target.png stdout -l chi_sim --psm 7
ä½  å¥½ , ä¸­ å›½
```

However, I got a mess.

## Question

why it got a mess when I use a `stdout` as the output? Is there anything I need to specific?

Comment: Maybe window command prompt does not support Chinese characters?

Comment: Maybe this is a tesseract's bug?

Comment: I tried running in Ubuntu and here's the result https://imgur.com/GDGekUh

Comment: This is a codepage issue. You can see that tesseract is outputting UTF-8 (multiple bytes per character), and cmd.exe is interpreting this output as a single-byte character encoding. That's why you get one character per byte. *A)* What does `chcp` return? *B)* What happens after you execute `chcp 65001`?

Comment: Proof: `国`, encoded as UTF-8, becomes the byte sequence `0xE5 0x9B 0xBD`. `0xE5 0x9B 0xBD`, decoded as [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (which is the default single-byte encoding on many Windows installations), are the 3 characters `å`, `›`, and `½`, which is exactly what you see.

Comment: @ExplodingGayFish Thank you. it is useful. maybe my window's command prompt doesn't support Chinese character well.

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you. I understand the reason cause its mess. I also tried `chcp 65001` which set to `utf-8` encoding. but still not work, so I come here to try my luck.

Comment: Also try redirecting the output into file and reading this file with the UTF-8 encoding. Alternatively try working on Powershell.